# 404 ошибка в WordPress

Tags: http-status-code-404, sitemap, поисковая-оптимизация

Создаю сайт на базе WordPress. Создал страницу с несколькими уровнями вложенности. Пример: `Главная/Краски/Краска_фирмы`. Через какое то время убрал дочерний элемент. Теперь просто: `/Краска_фирмы`.

Но в яндексе и гугле уже проиндексировались старые урлы. И при заходе на страницу `Главная/Краски/Краска_фирмы` выдает 404 ошибку.  Сайтмэп уже скинул и в гугл серч консоль и в яндекс. вебмастер. Но пока безрезультатно.

Как убрать индексирование уже несуществующей страницы? Ведь в админке WordPress нет страницы /`Главная/Краски/Краска_фирмы`.

Comment: В чём вопрос заключается?

Answer (score 0):

> Как убрать индексирование уже несуществующей страницы?

Если точно отдаётся 404, то ждать. Или заказать переиндексирование.